# Directory index forbidden

Tags: php

Já viram esse erro em PHP? Como resolver?

> [error]    Directory index forbidden by Options directive:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu servidor está proibindo a listagem dos conteúdos do diretório. Para habilitar a listagem, inclua isto no seu arquivo `.htaccess`:

```
Options +Indexes
```

Comment: sim amigo, ja coloquei porem persiste o erro !

Answer (score 1):

> Directory index forbidden by Options directive.

Esse erro indica que não há nenhum arquivo padrão (*index.php, index.html..*) na diretório,  isso significa que ele irá mostrar a listagem de conteúdo do diretório, mas devido a diretiva [`Options -Indexes`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#options), isso será proibido pela configuração do servidor.

Para mudar essa configuração edite o arquivo `httpd.conf` ou `.htaccess` e procure pela diretiva `Options -Indexes` e altere o sinal de negativo **-** para positivo **+**, salve e tente novamente.

- [Documentação](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings).

Comment: coloquei la amigo, deu errado , ao inves de listar cai em pagina de erro !

Comment: @JJuniorCarneiro Retorna o mesmo erro? Fiz isso propositalmente aqui e consegui com o `Options +Indexes` resolver, tente o seguinte: deixe o `.htaccess` do jeito que estava e edite o `httpd.conf`. Procure por **Options** (atalho: CTRL + F no *Notepad*) e deixe-o assim: `Options +Indexes`, é necessário **reiniciar** o servidor para que se possa ver as alterações.

Comment: @JJuniorCarneiro Outra coisa, qual o Sistema Operacional? você usa *XAMPP*, *WAMMP*? na minha máquina o `httpd.conf` está em: *C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf*.

Comment: estou direto no cpanel já ! eu mesmo sou dono do server e ativei la tb ! erro persiste : Directory index forbidden by Options directive:

Comment: @JJuniorCarneiro Intrigante. Deve haver alguma coisa que esteja *passando*, as permissões do seu usuário é 711? Qual é a mensagem **completa** do erro?

Comment: [Thu Mar 19 12:27:39 2015] [error] [client 66.249.64.98] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /home/sisv2/public_html/arquivos/site.frissonestetica.com.br/

Comment: Internal Server Error  http://portal.ornamentacoesarruda.com.br/

Comment: @JJuniorCarneiro Não foi uma boa ideia, desfaça isso. Deve haver algum conflito para que esse erro persista, eu acho. Você tem acesso a um terminal/console? se sim, execute o comando: `grep -r -i "Options -Indexes " /home/SeuNomeDeUsuarioAqui`, isso vai procurar na sua pasta pela sequência `Options -Indexes`, veja se aparece algo.

Comment: @JJuniorCarneiro Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: JA sim muio obrigado

Comment: @JJuniorCarneiro Só por curiosidade, como foi que você resolveu?